# Como mostrar o chaves dum dicionário na ordem em que elas foram inseridas

Tags: python-3.x

Estou a tentar mostrar no idle as `keys` e os seus valores, mas gostaria de fazê-lo usando a ordem predefinida, e não o acaso.

Por exemplo, tenho este dicionário:

```
months = {'January':31,'February':28,'March':31,'April':30,'May':31,'June':30,
'July':31,'August':31,'September':30,'October':31,'November':30,'December':31}
```

Mas o seu conteúdo não é mostrado em ordem, ou seja primeiro "January" e depois "February", etc.

Como o posso fazer?

Answer (score 3):

**Nota:** *visto que ninguém respondeu, decidi dar uma reposta pessoal e formal*.

Este problema surge porque os standard tipos [*dict*](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) em *Python* são mutáveis e desordenados, ou seja a inicial ordem de inserção das `chaves:valores` não é mantida durante o ciclo de vida dum dicionário.

Uma das melhores soluções para este problema é de usar a classe [*OrderedDict*](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) do modulo [*collections*](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Para mais documentação e ajuda, veja estes posts:

- [Python dictionary sort by
  key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/python-dictionary-sort-by-key)
- [Dictionary in python with order I set at
  start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490855/dictionary-in-python-with-order-i-set-at-start)
- [Why dictionary values aren't in the inserted
  order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061380/why-dictionary-values-arent-in-the-inserted-order)
- [How do you retrieve items from a dictionary in the order that
  they're
  inserted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60848/how-do-you-retrieve-items-from-a-dictionary-in-the-order-that-theyre-inserted)